# Как правильно офрмить запрос

Tags: sql, postgresql

Суть проблемы: Мне надо вначале получить определенные новости с запроса по критериям, а потом с помощью ROW_NUMBER() получить опред количество этих новостей.

Запросы которые у меня есть:

```
WITH news 
AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY creation_date DESC) 
AS row_id, news_id, author_id, tittle, news_text, creation_date FROM news) 
SELECT * 
FROM news 
WHERE (row_id BETWEEN 1 AND 3)
```

и

```
SELECT * FROM news
WHERE to_tsvector(tittle) @@ to_tsquery('tags')
```

Вот что мне примерно надо, но это выдает ошибку

```
SELECT * FROM news AS news1 
WHERE to_tsvector(title) @@ to_tsquery('ta') OR title LIKE '%ta%' 
WITH news1 AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY creation_date DESC) AS row_id, 
    news_id, 
    author_id, 
    title, 
    news_text, 
    creation_date 

    FROM news), 
news2 AS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM news1 
    WHERE (row_id BETWEEN 1 AND 2)
    )
```

Comment: *Мне надо вначале получить определенные новости с запроса по критериям, а потом с помощью ROW_NUMBER() получить опред количество этих новостей.* Вот Вам ТОЧНО нужны два независимых набора данных, один из которых является подмножеством другого?

Comment: мне надо чтобы к новостям из второго запроса, применялся первый запрос

Comment: Правильно ли я понял, что первый запрос можно упростить до: 
`SELECT * 
FROM news 
ORDER BY creation_date DESC
LIMIT 3
`
?

Comment: теоретически да, на деле думаю нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Таблицы идут по порядку. Первый запрос такой

```
    SELECT * FROM news
    WHERE to_tsvector(title) @@ to_tsquery('ta') OR title LIKE '%ta%'
```

Он выдаёт результат. Если к результату этого запроса нужно опять обратиться, то можно представить его ввиде `with`

```
WITH temp_news AS (
    SELECT * FROM news
    WHERE to_tsvector(title) @@ to_tsquery('ta') OR title LIKE '%ta%' 
)
```

Теперь к этому запросу можно обратиться как будто он таблица, только имя таблицы уже будет не `news` как в первом варианте, а `temp_news`.
Теперь можно сделать с новым запросом тоже самое.
В итоге весь код может выглядеть так:

```
WITH temp_news AS
(
    SELECT * FROM news
    WHERE to_tsvector(title) @@ to_tsquery('ta') OR title LIKE '%ta%' 
),

result_news AS 
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY creation_date DESC) AS row_id, 
    news_id, 
    author_id,
    title, 
    news_text, 
    creation_date 
    FROM temp_news
)

SELECT * 
FROM result_news 
WHERE (row_id BETWEEN 1 AND 2)
```

Comment: ошибку выдает near "as" LINE 9

Comment: Да там опечатка была на 9 строке, теперь должно работать

Comment: Да, теперь все работает, но немного наооборот, надо порядок запросов поменять

Comment: надо вначале выполнить нижний запрос, а потом с результатами нижнего верхний запрос

Comment: Тут главное разобраться откуда будет FROM во всех трех запросах и прописать его. По сути можно делать WITH tablename AS () и внутри писать любой SELECT

Comment: я с этим with так и не разобрался, вроде по вашему примеру все понятно, но до дела доходит и я туплю.

Comment: я попытался сделать так, но ничего не получилось
(смотреть в самом вопросе)

Comment: Попробуйте исправленный вариант, синтаксис у вас не совсем верный был

Comment: спасибо вам большое за помощь

Comment: я понял как это работает благодаря Вам)